# Converting data from matrix to vector format

Tags: mysql, excel

I have huge set of data in an excel file in the following format

```
School_id   percentage  year    subject

1100        90          2005    maths
1100        95          2006    maths
1100        81          2005    science
2310        45          2007    biology
```

I want to convert this data to this format

```
School_id   year    maths   science  biology

1100        2005    90      81
1100        2006    95
23100       2007                      45
```

I dont have any idea for how to do this conversion. Will this be possible with excel or mysql or any other tool? Need some suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1 option is Excel Pivot Tables. Very simple and easy to manipulate. See <http://www.contextures.com/CreatePivotTable.html>

Comment: I'm confused about one thing: why do you have the option between Excel and MySQL?  A spreadsheet and a database are two very different environments.  I wouldn't suggest doing a database conversion in Excel, however, if that's the road you're considering.  If it's okay to handle this in a spreadsheet, this is a super natural application of Pivot Tables, like Scott suggested.  Here's a tutorial: This is Here's a tutorial.  http://www.wikihow.com/Create-Pivot-Tables-in-Excel

Comment: I'm not sure how to make this conversion and just wanted to know how can this be achieved...anyways thanks for the awesome replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea so like they said pivot tables. To get your results, I had to do it using CONCATENATE function. There might be a better way. But this is how I did it:

first do a CONCATENATE column:
[image: CONATENATE COLUMN]

Then insert your pivot table and select the right options:
[image: PIVOT TABLE]

Then de-concatenate your School_id and Year
[image: De-Concatenate 1]
[image: De-Concatenate 2]

Like I said there might be a better way to do this - but then you would just need to organize your headers the way you want them and you should have what you are looking for. Good Luck.

Comment: i've understood what you explained here...thanks...but i have a problem i.e, actually my dates are in the format **08/10/2005**..and when i'm trying to concatenate with school_id i'm getting some weird value like **1100/40035**..why is that happening?

Comment: Hi ven, That is happening because excel represents dates as numbers(example. 40035). So when the data feeds into the pivot table it is feeding the actual number value of the date. You just need to convert your date cells into text in your original data. In your case you probably want to use: =TEXT(A1,"yyyy") In other cases you could use =TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy") if you want the day and month as well.

Comment: Hi Ven, I'm not sure I understand you but I think I do. When you create a pivot table you cannot really reference the pivot table data unless you use the pivot table interface. However if you want to just treat the pivot table as normal cells then you can copy the entire area of the pivot table and then do a paste special(of values) to another location. Then you can work with the data and format it however you want. That is why I have two table that look like pivot tables in my pictures above. The top one is the actual pivot table and the bottom one is the copy and paste of that.